# parse "build.fingerprint" debug message

Tags: android, debugging, parsing, fingerprint

I'm an Android application development in Korea.
When you run an application that I made, the application will be terminated without any error message occasionally,
I can not proviso that "Build fingerprint" in adb came out to confirm anything.

Is there a way to be able to interpret the "Build fingerprint" I?
If, How should be interpreted?
thanks

```
  *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
  Build fingerprint: 'my-device-name'
  pid: 6691, tid: 6903, name: Thread-1380  >>> my-app-name <<<
  signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaad
      r0 00000027  r1 deadbaad  r2 401b5b0c  r3 00000000
      r4 00000000  r5 68a2aaf4  r6 67832050  r7 00000078
      r8 5f5dab44  r9 00100000  sl 67832050  fp 68a2ab4c
      ip 5f684e30  sp 68a2aaf0  lr 40187c89  pc 4018432a  cpsr 60000030
      d0  0000000000000004  d1  0000000200000000
      d2  00000000fffffe8a  d3  5f68cb547fffffff
      d4  e5962050e59a0008  d5  e59ac010e59ae000
      d6  4036000000000000  d7  4020800000000000
      d8  402813e541409f2e  d9  0000000000000000
                         .
                         .
                         .
                         .
                         .
```